# How to split a string value using the pipe symbol as separator?

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string using the pipe symbol '|'

In this scenario I can split the string value but if I 
have  a "bullet number" greater than (0-9), it prints only the first digit of the number.

Example: If input is `11. Welcome to java programming` 
It will print `1 Welcome to java programming`

This is my code so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String split_vls = "11. Welcome1. to java programming |1. Oops concepts |12. Encapsulation |3.Abstraction  |14.Inheritance  |5.Polymorphism";
    String[] Numeric_split = split_vls.split("\\|*(\\d+\\.)\\s*");
    for (String pipes_Split : Numeric_split) {
        System.out.println(pipes_Split);
    }
}
```

This is the output that I get:

> to java programming 
>   Oops concepts 
>   Encapsulation 
>   Abstraction
>   Inheritance
>   Polymorphic

This is the expected output:

> Welcome to java programming
>   Oops concepts
>   Encapsulation
>   Abstraction
>   Inheritance
>   Polymorphic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your expression takes exactly one "word character" between `|` and `.`. You need to allow "one or more":

```
String[] Numeric_split = split_vls.split("\\|*(\\w+\\.)\\s*");
//                                                ^
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ov9rUd)

Comment: Sir, If I have "." in sentence like: 11. Welcome. to Java programming. It is getting split the sentence. It is not achieve the Excepted output in this scenario. `Welcome
to java programming 
Oops concepts 
Encapsulation 
Abstraction 
Inheritance 
Polymorphism
`

Comment: @Chola You can replace `\\w` with `\\d` to avoid matching letters ([demo](http://ideone.com/GbHvfJ)).

Comment: Sir, I done some changes from your answer in my question, If i add any new number and ".". It Completely removing the previous word "Welcome" Completely. Please check my question. And Give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the values which you have in your string.

Your String:

```
String split_vls = "11. Welcome to java programming |1. Oops concepts |12. Encapsulation |3.Abstraction  |14.Inheritance  |5.Polymorphism";
```

Try this:

```
StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(split_vls, "|");
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Output:

> 11. Welcome to java programming
>   1. Oops concepts
>   12. Encapsulation
>   3.Abstraction
>   14.Inheritance
>   5.Polymorphism

or:

```
String[] Numeric_split = split_vls.split("\\|*(\\w+\\.)\\s*");
for (String pipes_Split : Numeric_split) {
    System.out.println(pipes_Split);
}
```

Output:

> Welcome to java programming
>   Oops concepts
>   Encapsulation
>   Abstraction
>   Inheritance
>   Polymorphism

Comment: But My Expected Result : Without any kind of number or bullet in front.
Welcome to java programming 
Oops concepts 
Encapsulation 
Abstraction  
Inheritance  
Polymorphic